# Wildcard subdomain redirection workaround

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, subdomain, aws-amplify, wildcard-subdomain

I have one application running on AWS amplify and have a custom domain associated with the app. One of my use cases is to have a dynamic number of subdomains (per customer based)
so I can have e1.example.com, e2.example.com, and so on.

But the problem is AWS amplify does not support wildcard subdomains and if I were to create subdomains programmatically, there is a limit of 50 subdomains.

So I thought of a workaround
App 1 - Have a separate server with .htaccess file and wildcard subdomains
App 2 - when any request comes with *.example.com it will redirect the request to newexample.com/e1 which is on AWS amplify.

Had a couple of questions around this

- Will this going to work as App 1 will be somewhere else and will only have a .htaccess file and nothing else.
- What could be the best place to have this redirector application? on AWS, which service can be the best fit, cost-wise too?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make this work with a simple Elastic Beanstalk application using nginx for redirection.

Another way would be to use the WEB_DYNAMIC Amplify platform which gives you access to the Amplify Cloudfront distributions. You can set up wildcard routing at the Cloudfront level, just make sure your Cloudfront default behaviour has a cache policy that forwards the host header. This would allow you to only work with *.example.com domains